# Every column on different line with one record SQL reports

Tags: sql, report, sqlplus

I am trying to make a report for a particular table emp something like this.

```
************************************************************
EMPLOYEE NUMBER : 1010
EMPLOYEE NAME : SARAH
JOB : DESIGNER
SALARY : 10000$

*************************************************************
EMPLOYEE NUMBER : 1011
EMPLOYEE NAME : HANNAH
JOB : DECORATOR
SALARY : 20000$
*************************************************************
```

But I don't know how to get every column name on different line.

```
 sql > break column on empname skip page
```

The above code does something like this.

```
 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
  7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000

 EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
  7840 QUEEN       PRESIDENT       4000
```

Please suggest what would be the code for it ? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the data in this format in some presentation layer (e.g. a text editor), you can simply select the columns concatenated together, separated by a newline:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT empno, ename, job, sal FROM yourTable;

    v_empno yourTable.empno%INT;
    v_ename yourTable.ename%VARCHAR2(100);
    v_job   yourTable.job%VARCHAR2(100);
    v_sal   yourTable.sal%NUMBER(10,4);
BEGIN
OPEN cur;
LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO v_empno, v_ename, v_job, v_sal
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;

    dbms_output.put_line('EMPLOYEE NUMBER : ' || v_empno || CHR(13) || 'EMPLOYEE NAME : '
                         || v_ename || CHR(13) || 'JOB : ' || v_job || CHR(13) || 'SALARY : ' ||
                         v_sal || '$' || CHR(13));
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
END;
```

Comment: But using the above sql statement, it does not provide me the desired output. It displays all the columns and one record in one line and then recursively the same for all.

Comment: @TrueDroider Can you try copying that ouput and pasting into an editor, say Notepad++?  If it worked, it should appear formatted properly there.  If not, then we need to find a way to get newlines in the select statement.

Comment: SALARY : 800$ER : 7369 EMPLOYEE NAME : SMITH
Query displays something like this, even in notepad++

Comment: @TrueDroider My last attempt: Use a cursor along with `dbms_output.put_line()`.  If this doesn't work, you should consider just dumping your data into a text editor and going from there.